# Can I get audio data from microphone in background task?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to implement a feature in Windows Phone 8, let it calculate decibel by using the audio data from microphone in background task. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access the microphone from a background task according to this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx

```
Unsupported APIs:
System.Windows.Media A/V Capture 
Microsoft.Xna.*
```